# How can I convert an NSString with printer commands into NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to send a series of printer commands to a Sato barcode printer.  For example:

```
<ESC>A
<ESC>H0120
<ESC>V0060
<ESC>$B,180,180,0
<ESC>$=Information
...
```

I have an open tcp/ip connection to the printer and simply want to write an NSData object, such as:

```
[connection write:data error:error];
```

wheras data is an NSData object.  I realize that I can insert the escape into a string using the binary value with \x1B.  For example:

```
NSString *printString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"\x1BA\X1BH0120\X1BV0060\X1B$B,180,180,0/X1B$=Information"];
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to translate my string to NSData for the write.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give an update on some of my findings in case someone stumbles upon a similar problem in the future.  My problem was that I needed to send a series of printer commands to a Sato barcode printer.  Sato uses a proprietary language that requires syntax like above whereas I needed to send commands like `<ESC>`A and `<ESC>`Z.  I had an open tcp/ip connection and kept trying several methods to send the commands with no luck.  I though the problem was in my translation to NSData.  I was close, but not close enough.  The problem turned out to be in my translation from a file to an NSString...not when I was converting the NSString to NSData.  I also had problems trying to use \x "escapes" to send the binary equivalent of `<ESC>`.  I finally settled on using the octal equivalent.

```
    // load the appropriate file as a string
    NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sato.txt"];
    NSError *firstError=nil;
    NSString *satoData=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding error:&firstError]; // the NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding was the key to correcting my problem here.
    satoData=[satoData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Description" withString:self.description];
    satoData=[satoData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ItemID" withString:self.itemId];
    satoData=[satoData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Quantity" withString:self.printQty];
    NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
    NSString *formattedDate=[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:now dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    satoData=[satoData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Date" withString:formattedDate];
    NSData *data=[satoData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [connection write:data error:error];
```

Here is a sample of some of the contents of the sato.txt file

```
\033A\033#E5\033Z
\033A\033H0120\033V0060\033$B,180,180,0\033$=ItemID
```

The \033 is the octal escapes for `<ESC>`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

`NSData *data = [printString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Choose the encoding that best suits your needs, apart from that it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Will the NSUTF8StringEncoding maintain the binary escapes?

Comment: Yes, it will. This is no difference from regular English text regarding the encoding. Just be careful when you have special characters of more exotic languages, they might be displayed wrong if you don't use a suitable encoding.

Comment: Okay.  I had tried this earlier and I wasn't getting my expected results.  I assumed that the escape sequences were not getting to the printer, and were being lost in the "translation."  It must have more to do with my connection to the printer.  I'll have to do some more research on how to connect to the network printer.  Thanks.